# Dimensions problem with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I'm having a difficulty to `NDSolve` a ODE due to the dimensions problem (according to the error message). Below is the code I have.
First of all are functions:

```
otime = 0; nzone = 5; iex = 6;T0 = 293.15;hd=150;
lj={6, 12, 18, 24, 29.5};
tmax={35.4, 17.7, 8.85, 5.9, 4.425, 3.97753};
webSpeed={5/6, 5/3, 10/3, 5, 20/3, 89/12};
TE={{383, 393, 403, 413, 298}, {383, 393, 403, 413, 298}, {383, 393, 403,413, 298}, {383, 393, 403, 413, 298}, {383, 393, 403, 413,298}, {383, 393, 403, 413,298}}; 
TA[t_, ie_] := If[t <= otime,T0,For[i = 1, i <= nzone, i++,If[t - otime <lj[[i]]/webSpeed[[ie]], Return[TE[[ie, i]]]]]]
VE={{36, 36, 36, 36, 36}, {36, 36, 36, 36, 36}, {36, 36, 36, 36,36}, {36, 36,36, 36, 36}, {36, 36, 36, 36, 36}, {36, 36, 36, 36,36}};
hi[ie_, i_] := (VE[[ie, i]]/36)^0.8 hd (293/TE[[ie, i]])^(2/3);
htc[t_, ie_]:= If[t <= otime, 0,For[i = 1, i <= nzone, i++,If[t - otime <lj[[i]]/webSpeed[[ie]], Return[hi[ie, i]]]]]
```

Then is the `NDSolve` equation:

```
NDSolve[{T'[t] == htc[t, iex] (TA[t, iex] - T[t]), T[0] == T0}, T, {t, 0, tmax[[iex]]}]
```

The ultimate goal is to `NDSolve` the ODE above by varying the index `iex` from 1, 2, 3, ..., iex 
But first of all I need to make sure the `NDSolve` can work! Below is the error message:

> NDSolve::nlnum: "The function value {0.0128667 Return[125.469] (-293.15+Return[383])} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {t,T[t]} = {8.9003*10^-308,293.15}."

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: It looks like you are misusing `Return`. Did you try removing it?

Comment: Check http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Return.html?q=Return

Comment: Thanks @Karsten7.! I tried to remove "Return". But so far seems like it's the only way I can think of to describe TA[t_,ie_] and htc[t_,ie_]. Since only when I used "Return" I can Plot both TA and htc without an error. Any suggestions for this part? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve so failed to do further clean-up, but the following code works:

```
Clear[TA, htc, message]

message[t_] := "You forgot to define a return value for t = "<>ToString@t;
TA[t_?NumericQ, ie_] := 
  Catch@If[t <= otime, T0, 
    Do[If[t - otime < lj[[i]]/webSpeed[[ie]], Throw@TE[[ie, i]]], {i, nzone}]; 
    Print@message@t];
htc[t_?NumericQ, ie_] := 
  Catch@If[t <= otime, 0, 
    Do[If[t - otime < lj[[i]]/webSpeed[[ie]], Throw@hi[ie, i]], {i, nzone}]; 
    Print@message@t];

sol = NDSolveValue[{T'[t] == htc[t, iex] (TA[t, iex] - T[t]), T[0] == T0}, 
  T, {t, 0, tmax[[iex]]}]

{{lb, rb}} = sol["Domain"];
sol = Plot[sol[t], {t, lb, rb}]
```

Comment: Thank you @xzczd ! It works with your new defined TA and htc! Although I can plot the results, I still somehow get an error after running NDSolveValue, which is : NDSolveValue::nlnum: "The function value {0.0128667\ (-324.842+Print)\ Print} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {t,T[t]} = {3.97753,324.842}"

Does this also happen when you run the code? Thanks!!

Comment: @DavidC Slightly different in v9.0.1, the function value in the warning is `{(-298.+Null) Null}`. If you still have difficulty in understanding the reason for the warning, try `TA[tmax[[iex]], iex]`.

Comment: Thank you @xzczd !! With your suggestion I found that there's a "=" missing :)